# Java LWJGL in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I want to use the LWJGL library in Eclipse, I extracted the files into C:\javalibs\lwjgl.
Now when I try to test the LWJGL library like this:

```
C:\javalibs\lwjgl>java -cp .;res;jar\lwjgl.jar;jar\lwjgl_test.jar;jar\lwjgl_util.jar;jar\lwjgl_fmod3.jar;jar\lwjgl_devil.jar;jar\jinput.jar; -Djava.library.path=C:\javalibs\lwjgl\native\windows org.lwjgl.test.WindowCreationTest
```

Normally there should open a game window from LWJGL, but DOS says that java is a non valid command or wrongly spelled.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `java -version` first - if this does not show java version information, make sure you have a Java installed and the path to the `java.exe` file on your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: now I have set the ;C:\Programs (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin to the system environment variables and after reboot when I type java -version in the DOS command window it says another time that java is a non valid command or wrongly spelled

Answer (score 0):

Is java added to the PATH environment of Windows?

```
My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> System Variables -> Path
```

add the path-to-java-bin-folder and reboot or login/logout and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have solved the problem with the java environment path and the following command:

```
C:\javalibs\lwjgl>java -cp .;res;jar\lwjgl.jar;jar\lwjgl_test.jar;jar\lwjgl_util.jar;jar\lwjgl_fmod3.jar;jar\lwjgl_devil.jar;jar\jinput.jar; -Djava.library.path=C:\javalibs\lwjgl\native\windows org.lwjgl.test.WindowCreationTest
```

works fine and returns the LWJGL game window.

Thank you very much.